# Embedding SVG such that you get both fallback to raster and ability to manipulate it by CSS

Tags: html, web, vector, svg

I am trying to embed an SVG with fallback to raster (gif), however I also want some hover effects to work. I am able to get both features to work, but not at the same time. I am able to either embed the SVG with fallback option by using one of the many different techniques or I can insert the SVG code inline and then CSS styles like `svg:hover rect {fill: #FFF}` etc. will work, but they won't work if I embed the svg using object, img etc. elements that allow fallback option to work.

So these embeds allow fallback option but will not work with CSS defined externally. If defining CSS internally, inside the actual SVG file, it appears it won't support :hover css effect. I am also unable to get a hover effect if including js triggers like onmouseover etc. as attributes on the shape elements in the SVG.

```
<svg width="120" height="24">
<image xlink:href="/content/images/master/downarrow.svg" src="/content/images/master/downarrow.gif" width="120" height="24" />
</svg>


<img class="downarrow" src="content/images/master/downarrow.svg" onerror="this.src=content/images/master/downarrow.gif">
```

If just including actual SVG code inline, this then works with CSS styles defined in external style sheet.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="arrow" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120px" height="24px">
<rect fill="#4363AE" width="119.872" height="24" />
<polygon fill="#CCCCCC" points="119.872,0.084 59.936,24 0,0.084 " />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the fallback image inside a `<foreignObject>` SVG element?

Inside an HTML document, the syntax would be something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="120" height="24" class="hoverSVG">
    <rect fill="#4363AE" width="119.872" height="24" />
    ... SVG markup goes here ...
    <foreignObject>
        <img src="fallback.gif" class="hoverGIF" width="120" height="24" alt="" />
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

The `<foreignObject>` syntax allows you to add class names to fallback elements, so you should still be able to apply a `:hover` style to the fallback image.

[This blog post has a bit more information](http://davidensinger.com/2013/04/inline-svg-with-png-fallback/), and [here's the W3C documentation on `<foreignObject>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects).

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, both the SVG and the image fallback will be loaded by the browser. 
>   [David Ensinger](http://davidensinger.com/2013/04/inline-svg-with-png-fallback/)

[Every hacky](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) solution to the problem comes with his own drawbacks, so my favourite approach is the most simple: wrap your svg inside a container along with your fallback element, then use modernizr `.no-svg`class to style them accordingly:

ex.

```
<div class="brand">
    <svg class="brand__logo brand__logo--svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="145px" height="152px">
        <path fill="rgb(50, 255, 50)" d="M144.256,121.891 C144.256,121.891 55.846,151.217 55.846,151.217 C55.846,151.217 0.635,76.196 0.635,76.196 C0.635,76.196 54.923,0.505 54.923,0.505 C54.923,0.505 143.685,28.746 143.685,28.746 C143.685,28.746 144.256,121.891 144.256,121.891 Z"/>
    </svg>
    <img class="brand__logo brand__logo--png" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="146" height="153">
</div>
```

If you don't mind adding an additional javascript library or if your are looking for an extensive svg features support you could check ["SVG for everybody"](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) which also support SVG spritemaps and makes easy to create accessible SVG.